# How to fix this data type mismatch error?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am setting up a database and one of my OpenForm commands is giving a data type mismatch error for the criteria expression. All of the fields involved are formatted as text so I don't know what's causing the error.

I have tried changing the data types of the fields but it hasn't solved the issue.

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_InvoiceInfo", acNormal, , "[Invoice#] = " & Me.txtInvNum
```

When txtInvNum is clicked then it should open frm_InvoiceInfo and set the Invoice# field to equal the clicked value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you state, your fields are all text values, you should enclose the criteria with single or double quotes, e.g.:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_InvoiceInfo", acNormal, , "[Invoice#] = '" & Me.txtInvNum & "'"
```

Or:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_InvoiceInfo", acNormal, , "[Invoice#] = """ & Me.txtInvNum & """"
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It worked but I had to modify it to look like this: DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_InvoiceInfo", acNormal, , "[Invoice#] = " & """" & Me.txtInvNum & """"